# Why use Cache-Control header in request?

Tags: javascript, caching, cache-control

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) on `Cache-Control` specifies the following:

> Standard Cache-Control directives that can be used **by the client** in an
>   HTTP request.

I thought that only servers send back information on whether a client should cache a response. Why would a client send a caching information to the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be any number of intermediate proxies between the client and server which do caching. The client can explicitly request explicit caching behaviour from any and all caching entities, things like:

- `max-age` - "I don't want a response older than X"
- `no-cache` - "I want a fresh response"
- `no-transform` - "I don't want it unless it's the original"
- `only-if-cached` - "Don't bother the origin server if you don't have it already"

As with all *requests*, servers have a certain leeway in whether to honour the request or not. Just because a client insists on an uncached response doesn't mean it's necessarily going to get it.

Comment: Say the server doesn't do any sort of caching, but the client would like to do so for performance. Can the client request the browser to cache a HTTP call even if the server doesn't do anything about it?

Comment: What about no-store ?

Comment: An example where the client's request is not honoured is the CloudFlare cache which ignores you to avoid DoS attacks as described here https://community.cloudflare.com/t/request-no-cache-header-is-ignored-by-cloudflare/201653/2

Comment: It appears that the _browser cache_ serves as an intermediary http cache, so it sees and respects `Cache-control` headers in the request.