# static content not caching in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I want to cache all my static content of mvc application.

I Added Web.config file like this in the Content folder
[image]

I got proper response header from my server.

[image]

Even after receiving the header with max-age attribute, The next Request to the server goes with **Cache-Control:  no-cache**

[image]

This again retrieve the whole data.

It is not caching.

I want to know What am i missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the static content being served? HTML? Image? Something else?

Comment: I am trying to cache css file

Comment: Is it a public css file that you are willing to share the link to, so we can test it?

Comment: Yes It is a public css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The no-cache in your screenshot is a **request** header not a **response** header.

It is likely being issued by your browser in response to you forcing a refresh (Control-F5). The browser is effectively saying 'please get me fresh data, I don't want the cached data'. The server-side can't control this - the client is the one making the request.

If you aren't forcing a refresh then you may have disabled your browser cache (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/34092 ).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544664/34092 .

Comment: Yes no-cache in my screenshot is a request header. But My Browser asks for the data even after the server set its response header(max-age=3600).

Comment: The browser is allowed to do that. You ultimately can't stop it doing that. Think of cache headers as 'hints' for the browser - it doesn't have to pay attention to them. Have you perhaps disabled the cache on your browser (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/34092)?

Comment: Then what might be reason for the browser asks for the data even after set its response header to max-age=3600

Comment: The main two reasons are the ones I have mentioned. You force refreshed the page (Control-F5) or you disabled the cache in your browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My Browser disabled cache when developer tool is Opened.