# Enable Caching of Javascript, CSS files which are included in a JSP file

Tags: javascript, jsp, browser, browser-cache, cache-control

I am trying to enable browser cache the javascript, css files of my web application. The document type I'm using is a JSP.

I see manifest.appcache is deprecated, what is the best way to implement caching so that browser caches the js, css files.

Below is my code

```
<html manifest="../manifest.appcache">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Web app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= contextPath %>/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= contextPath %>/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're sure the path exists? what do you get when you type the path in plain string

Comment: Yes it exists, I removed the @include file just to keep it clean, the path would be resources/app/app.js, app.css

Comment: what do you get when you do `<p><%= contextPath %></p>` inside the body

Comment: localhost:8080/resources

Comment: localhost:8080/resources + /app.js makes up to `localhost:8080/resources/app.js` you said the whole path is `resources/app/app.js` you are missing an `/app` there?!

Comment: my bad it is localhost:8080/resources /app, but the point is I want to enable cache on these files. How do i do it?

Comment: Please see my answer, you have to configure the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Expires` to your http ***response headers***. This will make the browser in the client side to save the component of the page until that date. 
If you wonder how to set the headers while sending a response, you have to know to configure your server either by using a back-end programming language, or a third party.

Please see  [expires header](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) .

Try adding this to your html file `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">`

Comment: maybe your client is sending `Cache-Control: no-cache` please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541077/why-is-cache-control-attribute-sent-in-request-header-client-to-server

Comment: try to set request headers to `Cache-Control: max-age=2592000` @Sai, it's all about request headers.

Comment: Something like this  <% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","max-age=2592000"); %>