# How to remove default headers in a xhr request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

My XHR request sent default `Cache-Control` header. However, the server side requires no such headers.So, what should I do to remove such default headers in a XHR request? I've already try to do like this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", null);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", undefined);
```

But none of them works.

Comment: They should be fine, as long as you do them before you send the request, but after you `open`

Comment: [Why is Cache-Control attribute sent in request header (client to server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544664/402037)

Answer (score 0):

I know  it's probaly too late. I had the same problem you had. I couldn't find  a way around it, my solution was to use fetch

```
fetch( 'someurl/api/send',
   {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers:{
    Authorization: authToken
    }
    })
```

formData is

```
formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', someFile)
```

This automatically set the appropriate headers.