# Browser not caching request

Tags: javascript, html, cache-control

I am trying to get my web-page to cache the below request because I do not think it will change very often. I read that to control caching one can set the Cache-Control header, but when I did it below and check in `Chrome -> Dev Tools ->Application -> Cache`
the cache is empty.

```js
   var myHeaders = new Headers();
   myHeaders.append('Cache-Control', 'max-age=345600;');

   var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers : myHeaders
  };


  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/countries", requestOptions);
    const json = await response.json();
```

Comment: cache headers should be send from server not client side.

Comment: oh makes sense, sorry I am new to this; trying to learn...

Comment: We all need to learn new things all the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Cache-Control attribute sent in request header (client to server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541077/why-is-cache-control-attribute-sent-in-request-header-client-to-server)