# Browser doesn't cache http response

Tags: browser, http-headers, cache-control

I have a http request `/api/speakers/` and I want it to be cached by browser.
So I added `Cache-Control` to the request headers:

```
headers: {
  'Cache-Control': 'public, must-revalidate, max-age=86400'
}
```

[image: Request headers]

`cache-control` appears in request headers, but every time it requests it gets new data from response. I am testing without refreshing page, so that is not the problem.
What am I doing wrong? How to tell browser to cache request responses and not to request it next one day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Cache-Control attribute sent in request header (client to server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541077/why-is-cache-control-attribute-sent-in-request-header-client-to-server)

Comment: "to the request headers"; the values you use would be typical for *response* headers.

Comment: @Joe No, my browser is not behaving like it's written here. It sends `cache-control`, but even if it's sent before, it sends request again and again.

Comment: You say your browser "sends cache-control". These would need to come *from* the server, in the response.

Comment: @Joe So `cache-control` is not the thing that I write in my code and send it to server? That is the thing that backender should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that `Cache-control` should be sent by frontend, so the browser understands it and caches requests. It turned out that backend sends headers in response so browser can cache requests. In my case, backend written in `Django` used `cache_page` and now browser caches everything perfectly.